# How would I go about unit testing this using pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm trying to unit test the below code using pytest but I'm completely unsure link a list value with the function I'm testing.

```
def already_exists(self, name) -> bool:
        for storm in self.storm_list:
            if storm.name == name:
                return True
        return False
```

This is the complete code from where I got the function from:

```
class Storm(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, wind_speed):
        self.name = name
        self.wind_speed = wind_speed
        super().__init__()

class control_Centre:
    def __init__(self):
        self.storm_list = []

    def already_exists(self, name) -> bool:
        for storm in self.storm_list:
            if storm.name == name:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def test_already_exists():
    s1 = Storm('Jeff', 10)
    c1 = control_Centre()
    c1.storm_list.append(s1)
    assert(c1.already_exists('Jeff') == True)
    assert(c1.already_exists('Dave') == False)
```

Bear in mind, your function doesn't actually check that two storms are the same, just that a storm with a given name exists in your 'control centre' object.